# Pandas dtype to SQLAlchemy mapping

Tags: pandas, sqlalchemy

Is there such a thing as a "built-in" mapping between Pandas supported dtypes and SQLAlchemy datatypes?

I am trying to find more elegant way to produce a SQLAlchemy schema from a dataframe than iterating through all cases... Or somehow intercept the schema to_sql would produce, without directly writing.

Browsing Pandas to_sql sources gives me the impression that this is done case by case (sql._sqlalchemy_type definition). So what I am looking for might not exist...

Comment: Could you be a little bit more specific? What exactly is the problem? Is it `string` (in Pandas DF) --> `CLOB` (in the SQL table) mapping or something different?

Comment: I am trying to generate a SQLAlchemy table definition, given a pandas dataframe structure, so I can dynamically load a dataframe into whatever target database. (The to_sql() function is not an option as I would like to control a bit more table-level options on my target - but it is close). So I am looking for a mapping that would determine the "default" SQLAlchemy datatype for a Pandas one. Such as 'int32' ->  INTEGER, ->'object'->'CLOB', 'bool' -> 'BOOLEAN', etc...

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57072280/14201379), I think it would be helpful: